# Why does my Ubuntu 18.04 require really slow mouse double-click?

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, vmware

Ubuntu 18.04 insists on really slow mouse double-clicks for me.  If I double-click too fast, it gets treated as a single click.  I'm running in a VMware Fusion 10.1.3 VM on a Macbook Pro host.

Ubuntu 18.04, not Windows:

- It happens on both the 18.04 standard Ubuntu flavor and on Lubuntu guests.
- It does not happen on 16.04 Ubuntu.
- It does not happen on a Windows 10 guest. (Quick double-click works.)

Tap, not Click:

- It happens when I double-tap the Trackpad.
- It does not happen when I do the *physical* double-click.
- It does not happen when I double-click a real mouse.

Other:

- It happens whether I set Ubuntu to a slow or a fast double-click speed.
- Triple-tap gets recognized as a double-click.
- I don't have a CPU-exhaust problem because CPU is about 10%.
- The *first* double-click after I login can be normal speed.

Work-arounds:

- Set the Ubuntu mouse double-click speed to a very long time, and click-pause-click.
- Triple-click.

I saw similar symptoms impacting someone with a Logitech trackpad.  That was traced to a defect in libinput and will be fixed in 18.10, but I tried the 18.10 daily and it is still there.

My *guess* is that the two taps from the Mac host are mapped to two very rapid mouse-down messages in the guest, and they are getting debounced.

How can I tell Ubuntu that it is OK to accept rapid double-clicks?

Answer (score 1):

It is debounce logic.  evemu-record shows that the second tap is perceived 8 ms after the first.

Here's a similar bug with different hardware: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libinput/+bug/1762536

I filed a bug report for the new hardware at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libinput/+bug/1796928